Jmeter SSE script throwing SSL errors related to trustStores
My Jmeter SSE (Server-side events) script fails with the following error:
javax.script.ScriptException: java.security.KeyStoreException: problem accessing trust store
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:320) ~[groovy-jsr223-3.0.20.jar:3.0.20]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyCompiledScript.eval(GroovyCompiledScript.java:71) ~[groovy-jsr223-3.0.20.jar:3.0.20]
    at java.scripting/javax.script.CompiledScript.eval(CompiledScript.java:93) ~[java.scripting:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.util.JSR223TestElement.processFileOrScript(JSR223TestElement.java:230) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JSR223Sampler.sample(JSR223Sampler.java:72) ~[ApacheJMeter_java.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:651) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:570) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:501) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:268) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.3]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583) [?:?]
Caused by: java.security.KeyStoreException: problem accessing trust store
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TrustManagerFactoryImpl.engineInit(TrustManagerFactoryImpl.java:72) ~[?:?]
    at java.base/javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory.init(TrustManagerFactory.java:277) ~[?:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.platformTrustManager(Platform.kt:80) ~[okhttp-4.12.0.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.OkHttpClient.<init>(OkHttpClient.kt:237) ~[okhttp-4.12.0.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.OkHttpClient$Builder.build(OkHttpClient.kt:1069) ~[okhttp-4.12.0.jar:?]
    at com.launchdarkly.eventsource.HttpConnectStrategy$Client.createHttpClient(HttpConnectStrategy.java:524) ~[okhttp-eventsource-4.1.1.jar:4.1.1]
    at com.launchdarkly.eventsource.HttpConnectStrategy$Client.<init>(HttpConnectStrategy.java:440) ~[okhttp-eventsource-4.1.1.jar:4.1.1]
    at com.launchdarkly.eventsource.HttpConnectStrategy.createClient(HttpConnectStrategy.java:138) ~[okhttp-eventsource-4.1.1.jar:4.1.1]
    at com.launchdarkly.eventsource.HttpConnectStrategy.createClient(HttpConnectStrategy.java:64) ~[okhttp-eventsource-4.1.1.jar:4.1.1]
    at com.launchdarkly.eventsource.EventSource.<init>(EventSource.java:117) ~[okhttp-eventsource-4.1.1.jar:4.1.1]
    at com.launchdarkly.eventsource.EventSource$Builder.build(EventSource.java:1045) ~[okhttp-eventsource-4.1.1.jar:4.1.1]
    at com.launchdarkly.eventsource.EventSource$Builder$build.call(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47) ~[groovy-3.0.20.jar:3.0.20]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125) ~[groovy-3.0.20.jar:3.0.20]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:130) ~[groovy-3.0.20.jar:3.0.20]
    at Script2.run(Script2.groovy:102) ~[?:?]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:317) ~[groovy-jsr223-3.0.20.jar:3.0.20]
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.security.KeyStoreException: jks not found
    at java.base/java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.java:922) ~[?:?]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TrustStoreManager$TrustAnchorManager.loadKeyStore(TrustStoreManager.java:377) ~[?:?]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TrustStoreManager$TrustAnchorManager.getTrustedCerts(TrustStoreManager.java:335) ~[?:?]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TrustStoreManager.getTrustedCerts(TrustStoreManager.java:57) ~[?:?]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TrustManagerFactoryImpl.engineInit(TrustManagerFactoryImpl.java:48) ~[?:?]
    at java.base/javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory.init(TrustManagerFactory.java:277) ~[?:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.platformTrustManager(Platform.kt:80) ~[okhttp-4.12.0.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.OkHttpClient.<init>(OkHttpClient.kt:237) ~[okhttp-4.12.0.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.OkHttpClient$Builder.build(OkHttpClient.kt:1069) ~[okhttp-4.12.0.jar:?]
    at com.launchdarkly.eventsource.HttpConnectStrategy$Client.createHttpClient(HttpConnectStrategy.java:524) ~[okhttp-eventsource-4.1.1.jar:4.1.1]
    at com.launchdarkly.eventsource.HttpConnectStrategy$Client.<init>(HttpConnectStrategy.java:440) ~[okhttp-eventsource-4.1.1.jar:4.1.1]
    at com.launchdarkly.eventsource.HttpConnectStrategy.createClient(HttpConnectStrategy.java:138) ~[okhttp-eventsource-4.1.1.jar:4.1.1]
    at com.launchdarkly.eventsource.HttpConnectStrategy.createClient(HttpConnectStrategy.java:64) ~[okhttp-eventsource-4.1.1.jar:4.1.1]
    at com.launchdarkly.eventsource.EventSource.<init>(EventSource.java:117) ~[okhttp-eventsource-4.1.1.jar:4.1.1]
    at com.launchdarkly.eventsource.EventSource$Builder.build(EventSource.java:1045) ~[okhttp-eventsource-4.1.1.jar:4.1.1]
    at com.launchdarkly.eventsource.EventSource$Builder$build.call(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47) ~[groovy-3.0.20.jar:3.0.20]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125) ~[groovy-3.0.20.jar:3.0.20]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:130) ~[groovy-3.0.20.jar:3.0.20]
    at Script2.run(Script2.groovy:102) ~[?:?]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:317) ~[groovy-jsr223-3.0.20.jar:3.0.20]
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: no such algorithm: jks for provider SunJSSE
    at java.base/sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getService(GetInstance.java:87) ~[?:?]
    at java.base/sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:206) ~[?:?]
    at java.base/java.security.Security.getImpl(Security.java:658) ~[?:?]
    at java.base/java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.java:919) ~[?:?]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TrustStoreManager$TrustAnchorManager.loadKeyStore(TrustStoreManager.java:377) ~[?:?]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TrustStoreManager$TrustAnchorManager.getTrustedCerts(TrustStoreManager.java:335) ~[?:?]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TrustStoreManager.getTrustedCerts(TrustStoreManager.java:57) ~[?:?]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TrustManagerFactoryImpl.engineInit(TrustManagerFactoryImpl.java:48) ~[?:?]
    at java.base/javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory.init(TrustManagerFactory.java:277) ~[?:?]
    at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.platformTrustManager(Platform.kt:80) ~[okhttp-4.12.0.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.OkHttpClient.<init>(OkHttpClient.kt:237) ~[okhttp-4.12.0.jar:?]
    at okhttp3.OkHttpClient$Builder.build(OkHttpClient.kt:1069) ~[okhttp-4.12.0.jar:?]
    at com.launchdarkly.eventsource.HttpConnectStrategy$Client.createHttpClient(HttpConnectStrategy.java:524) ~[okhttp-eventsource-4.1.1.jar:4.1.1]
    at com.launchdarkly.eventsource.HttpConnectStrategy$Client.<init>(HttpConnectStrategy.java:440) ~[okhttp-eventsource-4.1.1.jar:4.1.1]
    at com.launchdarkly.eventsource.HttpConnectStrategy.createClient(HttpConnectStrategy.java:138) ~[okhttp-eventsource-4.1.1.jar:4.1.1]
    at com.launchdarkly.eventsource.HttpConnectStrategy.createClient(HttpConnectStrategy.java:64) ~[okhttp-eventsource-4.1.1.jar:4.1.1]
    at com.launchdarkly.eventsource.EventSource.<init>(EventSource.java:117) ~[okhttp-eventsource-4.1.1.jar:4.1.1]
    at com.launchdarkly.eventsource.EventSource$Builder.build(EventSource.java:1045) ~[okhttp-eventsource-4.1.1.jar:4.1.1]
    at com.launchdarkly.eventsource.EventSource$Builder$build.call(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47) ~[groovy-3.0.20.jar:3.0.20]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125) ~[groovy-3.0.20.jar:3.0.20]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:130) ~[groovy-3.0.20.jar:3.0.20]
    at Script2.run(Script2.groovy:102) ~[?:?]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:317) ~[groovy-jsr223-3.0.20.jar:3.0.20]

Context:
I need to simulate SSE traffic on Jmeter. I followed this awesome Blazemeter blog post and am using JSR223 Sampler.  I am using launchdarkly's okhttp-eventsource-4.1.1 library for this. All the dependent libraries are already incporated into Jmeter's classpath.
In my script, I am:

Buiding my POST request (which triggers the server to start sending the chunks in the form of events) using EventSource.Builder object.  (say builder)

Creating an EventSource object using that builder object (EventSource eventSource = builder.build();)

Finally, start listening to the events via:


    eventSource.start();
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(Integer.parseInt(args[2]));
    eventSource.close();

Now, when I ran this script, I started seeing SSL related errors that said -
error: javax.script.ScriptException: com.launchdarkly.eventsource.StreamIOException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target


From what I understood from my research, this looked like a problem with Jmeter not able to read/reference/understand the Java trustStore which (correct me if wrong!) contains info on server-side certificates.
On a sidenote, the same POST request works perfectly fine if I use the plain-old Jmeter HTTP Sampler, except that it would wait for the all the chunks to complete and  throw the final response. (which kinda negates my need to receive chunk-by-chunk SSE events as the server streams back). This POST request also works perfectly fine with POSTMAN. (It has out-of-the-box support for SSE).
Back to the point - Assuming that is a problem related to launchdarkly's certificates, I followed this post and imported (via  keytool) their certificate file (exported .cer file from Chrome) onto Java's default trustStore. (/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-21.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/security/cacerts). This didn't work.
Then, I created my own custom trustStore (tried both jks and pkcs type). While this got rid of the PKIX path building failed error, it has now started throwing the error I mentioned in my first line (problem accessing trust store).
On Jmeter's end, basically, I am playing with the following properties on my bin/system.properties file.
javax.net.ssl.trustStore=<pathToMyCustomTrustStore> (or <pathToJavaDefaultTrustStore>)
javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=<myCustomPassword>' (or `changeit` in case of java trust store)
javax.net.ssl.trustStoreProvider=SunJSSE (tried `sun`, `SUN`, etc.)
javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=jks (tried pkcs as well). 

I even tried changing java.security file (located at /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-21.jdk/Contents/Home/conf/security on my system) and changed the keystore.type parameter from pkcs12 to jks. Nothing worked.
Tried using Jmeter's SSL Manager (I am not sure if that's even applicable in this case. It looks like something to be used in case of client-certificates)
Tried handling the system properties with Beanshell Sampler. Something on the lines of:
import org.apache.jmeter.util.SSLManager;
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore","/Users/srajimwale/reemasNewestTrustStore.jks");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword","reemas");
SSLManager.getInstance().reset();

I am using Jmeter 5.6.3 and the following version of Azul Zulu Java:
openjdk 21.0.2 2024-01-16 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Zulu21.32+17-CA (build 21.0.2+13-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Zulu21.32+17-CA (build 21.0.2+13-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)

Nothing worked so far and I am stuck at the point where, (supposedly) Jmeter is not able to reference the custom/Java's trustStores and throwing the SSL errors. (unless this understanding itself is flawed! Please let me know.)
Can someone suggest some path forward?
Already stated as part of the question.

Not really programming or development, but: (1) normally the truststore contains certificates (usually only root certs) for the CAs which issue server certs, not the server certs themselves, although Java (unlike some other things) can use a server cert in the truststore (2) case doesn't matter for the 'type' (really a JCA algorithm) but does for the provider: the provider for JKS or jks is SUN (only) and for PKCS12 or pkcs12 is SunJSSE (only) but 'pkcs' without 12 is just wrong (3) javax.net.ssl.trustStore* and javax.net.ssl.keyStore* are different things and NOT interchangeable

@dave_thompson_085  Thanks for clarifying (2) around the case.  For (3), yes, I realized later on further later that they are 2 different things.

Thanks everyone and Ivan for your valuable inputs. This did not resolve my issue. Here's what I did:

To get the certificates, I followed steps at the same launchdarkly article I provided before, except that this time I did not export certificate from Chrome (that gives you the certificate but not the certificate chain). I used openSSL command mentioned at the launchdarkly article.

I created a certificate chain as Ivan suggested (a .pem file this time and not a .cer file!). 2 certificates there - Root certificate, followed by launchdarkly domain's certificate.  I named this certificate chain file as launchDarklyCertificateChain.pem

I created (yet another!) brand new truststore, by running the keytool command that Ivan suggested. This did not work. Hence, I tried the below one as well, with the following differences:
 sudo keytool -importcert -trustcacerts -alias myNewAliasForLaunchDarkly -file /Users/srajimwale/Documents/launchDarklyCertificateChain.pem -keystore /Users/srajimwale/reemasYetAnotherFinalTrustStore.p12 -storetype pkcs12




I've used -importcert instead of -import (I did not see any -import command in the keytool documentation. Perhaps deprecated or something)
Added extension .p12 to the truststore
Explicitly added the -storetype parameter with pkcs12 as the value.


Finally, these are the properties I used on my Jmeter system.properties file:

javax.net.ssl.trustStore=/Users/srajimwale/reemasYetAnotherFinalTrustStore.p12
javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=<myPassword>
javax.net.ssl.trustStoreProvider=SunJSSE
javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=PKCS12 (Jmeter does accept both kind of truststores. There are some sources on the internet that say it accepts only .jks type, but seems like that's not true)
I am back to square one when it says:
javax.script.ScriptException: com.launchdarkly.eventsource.StreamIOException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:320) ~[groovy-jsr223-3.0.20.jar:3.0.20]


So what you finally got right was the combination of trustStoreType and trustStoreProvider, as @dave_thompson085 said. You didn't need to do most of this.

And also using the certificate chain instead of certificate. It didn't solve the problem though, unfortuntely.  :(

Let's take this guy as the example: https://expired.badssl.com/
If you try to access it using the following Groovy code in JSR223 Sampler:
def conn = new URL("https://expired.badssl.com/").openConnection();
def status = conn.getResponseCode();
log.info('Status code: ' + status)

you will get the following error:

Problem in JSR223 script JSR223 Sampler, message: javax.script.ScriptException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: validity check failed
javax.script.ScriptException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: validity check failed
some long text
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateExpiredException: NotAfter: Mon Apr 13 01:59:59 CEST 2015
at sun.security.x509.CertificateValidity.valid(CertificateValidity.java:277) ~[?:1.8.0_362]
at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.checkValidity(X509CertImpl.java:677) ~[?:1.8.0_362]

It means that JDK cannot build an SSL connection to the website. You need to explicitly trust the website in order to be able to establish SSL/TLS connection.
So you need to get the certificate chain which should look like this:
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIFSzCCBDOgAwIBAgIQSueVSfqavj8QDxekeOFpCTANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADCB
kDELMAkGA1UEBhMCR0IxGzAZBgNVBAgTEkdyZWF0ZXIgTWFuY2hlc3RlcjEQMA4G
A1UEBxMHU2FsZm9yZDEaMBgGA1UEChMRQ09NT0RPIENBIExpbWl0ZWQxNjA0BgNV
BAMTLUNPTU9ETyBSU0EgRG9tYWluIFZhbGlkYXRpb24gU2VjdXJlIFNlcnZlciBD
QTAeFw0xNTA0MDkwMDAwMDBaFw0xNTA0MTIyMzU5NTlaMFkxITAfBgNVBAsTGERv
bWFpbiBDb250cm9sIFZhbGlkYXRlZDEdMBsGA1UECxMUUG9zaXRpdmVTU0wgV2ls
ZGNhcmQxFTATBgNVBAMUDCouYmFkc3NsLmNvbTCCASIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQAD
ggEPADCCAQoCggEBAMIE7PiM7gTCs9hQ1XBYzJMY61yoaEmwIrX5lZ6xKyx2PmzA
S2BMTOqytMAPgLaw+XLJhgL5XEFdEyt/ccRLvOmULlA3pmccYYz2QULFRtMWhyef
dOsKnRFSJiFzbIRMeVXk0WvoBj1IFVKtsyjbqv9u/2CVSndrOfEk0TG23U3AxPxT
uW1CrbV8/q71FdIzSOciccfCFHpsKOo3St/qbLVytH5aohbcabFXRNsKEqveww9H
dFxBIuGa+RuT5q0iBikusbpJHAwnnqP7i/dAcgCskgjZjFeEU4EFy+b+a1SYQCeF
xxC7c3DvaRhBB0VVfPlkPz0sw6l865MaTIbRyoUCAwEAAaOCAdUwggHRMB8GA1Ud
IwQYMBaAFJCvajqUWgvYkOoSVnPfQ7Q6KNrnMB0GA1UdDgQWBBSd7sF7gQs6R2lx
GH0RN5O8pRs/+zAOBgNVHQ8BAf8EBAMCBaAwDAYDVR0TAQH/BAIwADAdBgNVHSUE
FjAUBggrBgEFBQcDAQYIKwYBBQUHAwIwTwYDVR0gBEgwRjA6BgsrBgEEAbIxAQIC
BzArMCkGCCsGAQUFBwIBFh1odHRwczovL3NlY3VyZS5jb21vZG8uY29tL0NQUzAI
BgZngQwBAgEwVAYDVR0fBE0wSzBJoEegRYZDaHR0cDovL2NybC5jb21vZG9jYS5j
b20vQ09NT0RPUlNBRG9tYWluVmFsaWRhdGlvblNlY3VyZVNlcnZlckNBLmNybDCB
hQYIKwYBBQUHAQEEeTB3ME8GCCsGAQUFBzAChkNodHRwOi8vY3J0LmNvbW9kb2Nh
LmNvbS9DT01PRE9SU0FEb21haW5WYWxpZGF0aW9uU2VjdXJlU2VydmVyQ0EuY3J0
MCQGCCsGAQUFBzABhhhodHRwOi8vb2NzcC5jb21vZG9jYS5jb20wIwYDVR0RBBww
GoIMKi5iYWRzc2wuY29tggpiYWRzc2wuY29tMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAA4IBAQBq
evHa/wMHcnjFZqFPRkMOXxQhjHUa6zbgH6QQFezaMyV8O7UKxwE4PSf9WNnM6i1p
OXy+l+8L1gtY54x/v7NMHfO3kICmNnwUW+wHLQI+G1tjWxWrAPofOxkt3+IjEBEH
fnJ/4r+3ABuYLyw/zoWaJ4wQIghBK4o+gk783SHGVnRwpDTysUCeK1iiWQ8dSO/r
ET7BSp68ZVVtxqPv1dSWzfGuJ/ekVxQ8lEEFeouhN0fX9X3c+s5vMaKwjOrMEpsi
8TRwz311SotoKQwe6Zaoz7ASH1wq7mcvf71z81oBIgxw+s1F73hczg36TuHvzmWf
RwxPuzZEaFZcVlmtqoq8
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----

Once done you need to add it to a truststore like this:
keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias expired.badssl.com -file certificate.pem -keystore /path/to/store.jks

And finally you can launch JMeter providing the path to the truststore like this:
jmeter -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/path/to/store.jks

That's it, you should get the following message in the log now:
INFO o.a.j.p.j.s.J.JSR223 Sampler: Status code: 200

Repeat the above steps for the website you're going to test and it should resolve your issue.
More information:

Difference Between a Java Keystore and a Truststore
Configuring JMeter
Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide


The question is not about certificates, it is about an unrecognized trustsstore type, an issue your answer does not address in any way.
